# Salesforce1 Navigate a user to "Create new record" page mobile with a url

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile-url-scheme

I am creating a vue app that loads an iframe to show specialized information about an account. If the user wants to edit the account shown there is a hyper link and the href to the hyperlink looks like: `'salesforce1://sObject/[record_id]/view'`. This url successfully navigates the user away from the iframe and back into the salesforce mobile app to view the account.

I wish to make something similar like this but instead of viewing an existing account I want the href link to create a new one and I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas which you can try:-

1. Use **/lightning/o/Account/new?** URL on onClick in your lightning component to create a record of type account. You can change the object name and it should work in Lightning mobile app.
2. Use lightning:navigation component to navigate to a given pageReference or to generate a URL from a pageReference. It is supported in Mobile app too.

Read more about that here:-  [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)

Comment: None of these worked. Thank you for helping me though. Ill find another solution.

Comment: Can you tell what is happening if you are following the above option?

Comment: The first solution routes the user but it routes them within the iframe, I want it to exit the iframe and navigate them into the app. The second option just doesnt work at all.